# ASP.NET cache on client or server

Tags: asp.net, caching

If you set caching (as below) in an [HTTP handler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307985), will it be cached on the server or client or both?

```
_context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
_context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(180));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the following call:

```
_context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
```

it turns out that in addition to setting the `Cache-Control: public` HTTP header, **it also enables server-side output caching**.

Answer (score 1):

This sets the http header, which means it will be cached by:

- The client
- A server "on the way" to the client, such as an ISA server

Answer (score 0):

The code you used above will cache the content on the clients browser.

If the expiry date of the content is within the time specified then the browser (client side) will issue a 304 "Not Modified" i.e. The Content is cached and not re fetched from the server.

Hope this helps

G

Answer (score 0):

Cache-Control: public to specify that the response is cacheable by clients and shared (proxy) caches.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcacheability(VS.71).aspx

Regards
--Jocke